# Resurrection of my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

My MacBook Pro was pronounced "dead on arrival" by the Apple Genius after sustaining injuries from liquid that had been spilled in my brief case. Despite the purchase of a new MacBook Pro Retina I find myself unable to completely detach from the MacBook that drowned in a pool of sweetened iced tea while under my watch. Is there a financially practical solution for resurrecting my MacBook Pro with the 17 inch display and solid state hard drive? It's been stored in my closet and has never started since the fatal accident.

Comment: Consider giving it a proper burial with honers and Eulogy, but do not use Cremation.

Comment: @Buscar 웃--Buscar, I have difficulty with the concept that it cannot be revived and am hoping to hear from someone who has encountered a similar disaster and found a remedy. I apparently suffer from Mac separation anxiety evident by the fact I've maintained and use upon occasion, my first Mac G4 that was purchased in 2006. If only my Macs could talk....

Comment: Well, I understand and feel with you. Now it depends what kind of surgeon are you. Short of making a little Frankenstein we could go and replace many parts to bring it back to life (at cost).

Comment: You should be able to part out the dead MBP and at least take out it's SSD which is sealed is probably working fine. My guess is the sugar in the tea did a number on the exposed motherboard and all the small connections so that piece is probably not worth messing with.

Comment: @Buscar웃 and Richard-Since you've mentioned Frankenstein, I will certainly consider weighing the good against the bad and the ugly. When you refer to removing the dead and broken parts in an attempt to bring what is dead back to life, I feel strangely haunted with images of my ex-husband which is enough to cause me to rethink the horror of resurrecting what is hopelessly broken and nonfunctional. Perhaps I'll ask that my Mac be blessed and sprinkled with holy water before wrapping it in a shroud and burying it in an unmarked grave in a cemetery known as Giglia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say...the only solution is...

[image]

Comment: It was a good run, my MacBook Pro and me. But I cannot look back at my seventeen inch Mac, when I've replaced it with Retina technology.